# intellij and or eclipse equivalent of sublime text's select text and edit?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, sublimetext2

it is kinda hard to explain what I am talking about

easier is have a look at this video at minute 18:50 until 19:00

[sublime's nifty text block select and change](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxmEUOADhnE)

he selects a text block, then selects other text blocks with it, and changes them all together at once

is there something like this in intellij or eclipse?

Comment: php or java, doesn't matter

Comment: With Eclipse 4.22 (Q4 2021), see also "[Eclipse - multiple line editing on any substring like in Sublime Text and Atom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70316624/6309)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called [Multiple Selections](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80056), and it is not yet implemented in official IntelliJ, there is just my [prototype](https://github.com/krasa/intellij-community/tree/multiEdit5) which works pretty much like Sublime, and if you want, you can build it and give it a try :).

Edit: It is now implemented in some form in [official IntelliJ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/)

Comment: "you can build it and give it a try" ? you give me shivers, I see myself spending hours trying to build and use it, and it will be buggy finally. It really looks nice, is there no final plugin available for download somewhere? I am still on intellij 12.1.6, i could move to 13 no problem

Comment: ah now I get it, this is built into the community edition of intellij. What backdraws can i expect? I am developing joomla web application software using PHP

Comment: The only backdraws are, that you will not be able to use ultimate version (I think), and since I pull all new changes from an origin, then there might be new bugs as well as new unreleased fixes. Otherwise worst thing that can happen is that you will not use multi selections, but just normal editing. And if you trust my [reputation](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/space/index?pr=idea&lg=meo), I could give you link to already compiled build which I use at work.

Comment: But I guess you need ultimate version and PHP plugin, so tough luck.

Comment: just post the link here for other fellow coders, i fear i'll just have to wait :-S

Comment: Rather no, by the time someone next comes across this, the build will be already old. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44789/discussion-between-meo-and-toskan)

Comment: @Meo Has there been any word from JetBrains on bringing the patches into the real repo? I think I'm stuck since I don't have the time to try to get IDEA to compile on my machine and it is understandable you wouldn't want to get into the business of making binaries for everyone.

Comment: @ShawnFumo They started to work on it 3 weeks ago, dunno what takes them so long with all that inspiration from me :) I already have binaries: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/roe5f7dg2alt5tk/FfB_0DpvYa

Answer (score 0):

There might be an option **in Eclipse** to *Rename In File* through Quick Assist (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>), but it usually applies to variables and not simply every occurrence of a string in the file.