# Eclipse - multiple line editing on any substring like in Sublime Text and Atom

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, sublimetext3, atom-editor

Is there nowadays any way to achieve in Eclipse multi-line editing **on any substring** like in Sublime and Atom? <sub>(CTRL+D for these)</sub>

A reference to a Plugin would be ok too.
( I found this plugin but it seems abandoned:
https://github.com/caspark/eclipse-multicursor )

I also found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583201/eclipse-multiple-text-selection-like-sublime-text-2) here on stackoverflow but it's 6 years old. Wondering whether something came out in the mean time.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9460968/2834978)?

Comment: Thanks for that @LuisMuñoz. It does not work in the same way as Sublime/Atom/IntelliJ but better than nothing. (ALT+Shift+A - Multi line editing **only if aligned on the same column**).

Comment: I'd still like to know if there's a plugin that would allow us to user the classical multi cursors

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse 4.22 (Q4 2021) now comes with:

> ### [Multiple text selection](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/platform.php#multi-selection)
>
> Support for multiple selection has been added to Text Editors.
>
> Multi selections allow most edit operations (text replacement or insertion, extend selection to next word or to next line, copy/paste...) to apply simultaneously on all ranges.
>
> [image: multi edit -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.22/images/multi-carets.png]
>
> Multiple strategies are available to enable multi-selections:
>
> - Turn a block selection into a multi-selection using the To multi-selection command,
> - Add a caret with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>,
> - Use the new `Select All` button on the `Find/Replace` dialog.

---

Eclipse 4.24 (Q2 2022) comes with:

> ### [Action commands for multiple carets/selections](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.24/platform.php#multi-select-commands)
>
> [image: https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.24/images/multi-selection-demo.gif]
>
> That includes:
>
> - Multi selection down relative to anchor selection (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>)
> - Multi selection up relative to anchor selection (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>)
> - End multi-selection (e.g. <kbd>ESC</kbd>)
> - Add all matches to multi-selection (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>)
> - Multi caret up (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>)
> - Multi caret down (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift-<kbd>Down</kbd>)</kbd>

---

July 2023: [Manohar Bhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7293057/manohar-bhat) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541244/eclipse-multiple-line-editing-on-any-substring-like-in-sublime-text-and-atom/70316624#comment135376594_70316624):

> One thing that is not supported and makes multi caret almost useless: After adding multi caret up or down at the beginning of two or more lines, if you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>, it should select next word's under all caret's.
> But it selects only one word and multi carets disappear.
>
> Same thing is also mentioned for DBeaver which is also based on eclipse framework, in [`dbeaver/dbeaver` issue 6064](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6064#issuecomment-1024359946): "Add support for Multiple selections (multi-cursor)".

Comment: Note: One thing that is not supported and makes multi caret almost useless. After adding multi caret up or down at the beginning of two or more lines, if you press ctrl+shift+right it should select next word's under all caret's. But it selects only one word and multi carets disappear. Same thing is also mentioned for dbeaver which is also based on eclipse framework. https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/6064#issuecomment-1024359946

Comment: @ManoharBhat Good point, thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.